# Inserting with no values in it

Tags: php, joomla

I am posting the Code here please help.

> Every time i run this a new row is created, but no data is saved in
>   it, except the id.Is there any geters and setters in it.

Trying to insert a value in the Database using post method. Its saving a new row into the table, but the value is not saved. I don't know what happened.

```
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
class NewbookController extends JControllerLegacy
{
public static function getHello($params)
    {
 $db =JFactory::getDBO();
  echo $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo $img =$_POST['image'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO `book_newbook` (`id`,`name`,`image`)
    VALUES ('','$name', '$img');";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query(); 
//$result = $db->loadResult();
//return $result;
}
}
?>
 <form action="index.php" name="adminForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Name : 
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
        </p>
  <p>Image : 
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
  </p>
  <p> 
    <input type="submit"  value="OK" name="ok"/>
      </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you ready **any** of the Joomla documentation? If not I suggest you do as you're not using Joomla coding standards for your `$_POST` methods or database query. Assuming the code you have posted is all in 1 file, you will also need to ready up on MVC and how to create a component.

Comment: @Lodder I started today afternoon. Sorry about the coding standards.

Comment: You should read joomla component structure documentation http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla in a non-programming issue. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla?referrer=GJNkvklnM7gqU7r0cS-muA2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started on a few things:

```
$input = new JInput;
$name = $input->get('name', '', 'post');
$img = $input->get('image', '', 'post');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('id', 'name', 'image');    
$values = array($db->quote($name), $db->quote($image));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__book_newbook'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Note: see the prefix before the database table >> `#__book_newbook`

Please bare in mind this is something to get you started. You still need to have a read of [Developing an MVC Component for Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component) so that everything is up to scratch.

Hope this helps

Comment: Alright mate, I'll give you that one :)

Comment: thx :), apologies for the rant before but just trying to drum it into people that Joomla methods are so different to stand alone PHP and if one is going to use Joomla, they may as well make full use of it's features. It's like a whole new world of coding.

Comment: I appreciate that but without the basics in Joomla, database queries are a quite bit further along the learning curve.

Comment: @Lodder thanks mate (Y) appreciate it :)

Comment: @user2731899  - You're more than welcome

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your db table key is `'id'`, you are inserting this as `''`, i.e. blank. this will seldom work if at all. Replace with

```
 "INSERT INTO `book_newbook` (`name`,`image`)
    VALUES ('$name', '$img');";
```

and ID should be updated automatically.

Regarding updating a database with Joomla, read up on their standards for database queries as they have their own way of doing things - http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: I have given auto increment in the table does that still make an issue

Comment: Yes. You are trying to force define the value as '' where it should be unique and so any attempt at more than one entry with the id as '' will not be entered, if you have set your primary key ad ID.

Comment: but every time i insert a new roq is createdd with no values in it except the id

Comment: Read  http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: sorry not working :( still same issue

Comment: Ok can you please update your Q with what you have just tried.

Comment: this doesn't use Joomla coding standards either

Comment: @Lodder - Try reading the fourth comment as well as my whole answer.

Comment: @Daniel - I have read everything, you should update your answer for the DB query using these standards ;)

Comment: @Lodder - I told him/her to read the joomla dev docs as obvious that they have not. My point was an issue with basic MySQL. I note that you have not provided an answer yet, your highness, however you seem awfully good at marking others down.